# Tablesorter custom date with possible other values

Tags: jquery, sorting, date, tablesorter

I am using latest version of the tablesorter plugin and I need to sort a column in a special way.

Values can be like this:

### [image: Values can be like this]

I need to order by the date, so values like **Q4 (31-12-2010)** should show up as the first

The date format is like: **dd-mm-yyyy**

Is this even possible?

Comment: It looks like you just have it in alphabetical order.  Is it supposed to be sorted by the date of the quarter, instead?

Comment: Yes, it should sort on the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I redid this using their custom parsers

http://jsfiddle.net/rTrqz/2/

Seems work work for your purposes.

The important parts are here:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'quarters',
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        s = s.toLowerCase().replace(/q[0-9]/,'').replace(/\(/,'').replace(/\)/,'');            
        match = s.match(/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20\d\d)/);
        return match[3] + match[2] + match[1]; 
    },
    type: 'text'
});
```

Comment: Can you explain the sortList, I wish to use it like: $("table").tablesorter({
    headers: { 0: { sorter: "sorter" } }
   });

Comment: Sorry I am new to the plugin, just looked at it before I posted, lemme take a look at that particular initialization. The sortList version [6,0] just sorts it by the 7th column (0 index) when it loads. Will get back to you after I look at the docs a little more.

Comment: Meep, I actually went through and did it with a custom parser too :O might want to consider giving that one a try since it's probably more future proof. But, up to you! Both should work.

Comment: Awesome man thanks, I will give you bounty in a few hours. I need to wait before. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of how I would do this:

```
     $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'quarters',
        is: function (s) {
            return false;
        },
        format: function (s) {
            var match = s.match(/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20\d\d)/);
            if (match)
            {
               return match[3] * 1000 - match[2] * 100 - match[1] * 10;                
            }
            else return 0;
        },
        type: 'text'
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("table").tablesorter({
            headers: {
                0: {
                    sorter: 'quarters'
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

You can adjust the return for the Not Valid Date part to whatever integer you want (0 makes it come before the earliest date.)

Comment: Seems like it will still sort randomly. It should sort on year, month, date. (then the quarters will automatic line up)

Comment: have you tried it?  it sorts based on the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and the date matched in the regex.  it works fine for me.

Comment: This works good. Is it possible to sort it on Year, month, day? Some dates from 2010 shows up last in the quarter

Comment: I changed the way the sort value was determined.  I just made it up on the fly, but it seems to work, if you're really going to use it I'd sit down and think about what might go wrong with this method.  I also updated the regex to fix a small bug.

Comment: Okay, seems like I never implenented this probably. It does seem to have some flaws. Q2 (16-04-2013) will show up first and then Q1 (01-01-2011) and so on. And in the end it will be Q4 (31-12-2010) and the "TBD".. Do you know a fix? :-)